# how to disable on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
    var x = "<img src='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='plusimage' name='plusbuttonrow'/><span id='plussignmsg'>(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>";
    if (qnum == <? php echo(int) $_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?> ) {
        $('#mainPlusbutton').replaceWith(x);
    }
    //append rows into a table code, not needed for this question
}....
$('.plusimage').live('click', function () {
    plusbutton($(this));
});

function plusbutton(plus_id) {
    // Set global info
    plusbutton_clicked = plus_id;
    // Display an external page using an iframe
    var src = "previousquestions.php";
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
    return false;
}
```

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">
<table id="question">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <a onclick="return plusbutton();">
        <img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
      </a>
      <span id="plussignmsg">
        (Click Plus Sign to look up Previous Questions)
      </span>        
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="questionBtn" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In the code above I am able to replace an image with another image when the if statement is met. But my problem is that when the image is replaced, it does not disable the on click event. My question is that when the image is replaced, how do I disable the onclick event `onclick="return plusbutton();`?

Could unbind click work in this situation. I don't want to use `href=#` because I don't want to include # at the end of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$('.plusimage').off('click');` to disable click events (unbind and live are deprecated on jQuery < 1.7 , but still supported).

If you are looking for a way to allow only one click on an element you can use this:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var x = "<img src='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='plusimage' name='plusbuttonrow'/><span id='plussignmsg'>(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>" ;

    if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {
       $('#mainPlusbutton').replaceWith(x);
       //If the condition hold, then deactivate the click event!
       $('form table a').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else{
       //If the condition is false, click event is activated removing the disabled class
       $('.form table a').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    //append rows into a table code, not needed for this question
}
```

Add this click event and remove the `onclick="return plusbutton();` inside link element:

```
//Click event activated only if the disabled class is not set
$('form table a:not(.disabled)').on('click', function() {
   plusbutton($(this));
});
```

Comment: so in if statement should I do what you stated or should I do something like `$('.plusimage').unbind('click');` in the if statement?

Comment: inside if statement... but check my edit, with another way to achieve this

Comment: All I want is that if the if statement is met, that it disables the onclick straight way. If you look inside the if statement, it replaces the image straight away, I want to disable the on click event straight away when the if statement is met. So which line of code is best to do this and include in the if statement?

Comment: then insert `$('.plusimage').off('click');` after `$('#mainPlusbutton').replaceWith(x);` That way you will deactivate the click event.

Comment: Ok I will give it a go and hopefully it will work. I will let you know the outcome... I tried the `$('.plusimage').off('click');` but it has not disabled the click event

Comment: If I change the live(click) function then wouldn't that just disable the onclick straight away? I only want it to be disabled when the if statment is met so how does it know when it should disable the onclick is the issue I have with your second answer

Comment: Still not working tom, Arrgghhh!, still performing the click event. This is a pain :)

Comment: ok, just one thing... which button you want to disable? the link or the button?

Comment: ohh, the problem is that you are using `onclick="return plusbutton();"` inline... you need to delete that and use jquery for that.

Comment: Ok so please put me out of my misery and tell me you know how to do this?

Comment: ok! now it should work!! (check update) in any other case, put the code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and show it to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.plusimage').live('click', function() {
  if (qnum != <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {
    plusbutton($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: I only want the onclick to be disabled when the if statement `if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {` has been met, the onclick event is always enabled until this if statement has been met. Could your code be able to do this?

Comment: unbind of live() is die() but these days it's on() and off(). To make something only happen once its one()

Comment: What I mean is that what do I put in the if statement so that when the if statement is met, then it will disable the onclick event, at the moment this code seems like it wil disable the onclick event at any time, I only want to disable it when the if statement has been met

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not totally correct, as it didn't run in JsFiddle but should give you some hints if you join it with Tom's question.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeanpaul1982/38hjZ/15/

perhaps the reason is that I removed some of the php as there is no way to echo or check for the session variable, although I believe that for that you should check firstly if the $_SESSION variable exists.

@add Tom: Made some small modifications on the PHP echo

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var x = "<img src='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='plusimage' name='plusbuttonrow'/><span id='plussignmsg'>(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>" ;

 <?
 //to avoid typecasting just declare the variable as a number
 $text_question_res=0;

session_start(); //If session has not started previously
if(isset($_SESSION['textQuestion']) ) $text_question_res.=$_SESSION['textQuestion'];
echo <<<EOD

if (qnum == $text_question_res) //expected to be a number

EOD;

//    if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {


       $('#mainPlusbutton').replaceWith(x);
       //If the condition hold, then deactivate the click event!
       $('.plusimage').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else{
       //If the condition is false, click event is activated removing the disabled class
       $('.plusimage').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    //append rows into a table code, not needed for this question
}
```